# A terminal command for a rooted Android to remount /System as read/write

Tags: android, system, root, mount

I'm writing an android app that needs to copy a file to the "/system" partition at runtime. I've got the commands to run "su" and can successfully request SuperUser permissions and run commands as root. But I don't know how to make this app universal across multiple devices, because the mount command can differ depending on where the /system is actually mounted. Here's the command that's used most offen:

```
mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

But I know that mtdblock3 could be different on some devices (and for that matter, i guess so could yaffs2). So, my question is: Is there a universal command that will work on all phones? Or is there a way to find out at runtime what the correct parameters are?

Comment: None of the solutions work for Marshmallow (maybe even >=5.1.1)

Comment: works just fine for me under 5.1.1, but I don't have a Marshmallow device to test

Comment: **workaround for pushing files on M**: adb push seems to fail if I push directly to /system. What I do: **1.** mount /system **2.** give permissions **3.** push to sdcard something **4.** su mv from sd to /system **5.** leave permissions as is, and system mounted because we like bad practices!

Comment: It works with Marshmallow (6.0) using Genymotion. mount -o remount,rw /system

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089694/adb-remount-permission-denied-but-able-to-access-super-user-in-shell-android

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can run the *mount* command without parameter in order to get partition information before constructing your mount command. Here is an example of the mount command without parameter outputed from my HTC Hero.

```
$ mount
mount
rootfs / rootfs ro 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw 0 0
tmpfs /sqlite_stmt_journals tmpfs rw,size=4096k 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,cpu 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock3 /system yaffs2 rw 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock5 /data yaffs2 rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock4 /cache yaffs2 rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
/dev/block//vold/179:1 /sdcard vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,uid=1000,gid=
1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,s
hortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

Comment: OK, that's great, thanks. One question, though -- from that output, I can find the line that has /system and parse the mount point and partition type. Is there any command that will just output that info for only /system (to avoid all the parsing)?

Comment: Nevermind -- I got it all parsed without any issues, but there is another problem: I can run other root commands just fine from within my app, but the "mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system" command has no effect. I get no errors, and it looks like it ran successfully, but /system stays as read-only. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I think you can not run the  "mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system" command with regular app permission. You should run it with root permission in order to take effect.

Comment: I'm running it under "su", meaning it has root permissions from the SuperUser app;

Comment: I recommend you read this thread on how to execute a command with [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594071/android-how-can-execute-a-chmod-on-rooted-devides]("root" permission)

Comment: I've already done that, and I actually posted a follow-up question with the exact code I use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481395/android-how-to-mount-filesystem-in-rw-from-within-my-apk-rooted-of-course

Answer (score 126):

I use this command:

```
mount -o rw,remount /system
```

Comment: Doesn't work, spitting out `Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory`. Samsung Sidekick 4G.

Comment: You need to be root in order for this to work. Run `su` in your shell prior to executing this command.

Comment: When done, I suggest to remount it read-only again, for safety reasons. `mount -o remount rw /system`

Comment: @naXa - if I remember correctly, the suggested command didn't work, but my version did... it probably depends on the OS / terminal version you're running. I should have been more clear about that.

Comment: This does not work for me. I tried: `mount -o remount,rw /system`, `mount -o rw,remount /system` and `mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/mmcblk0p23 /system`, with the two possibilities `remount,rw` and `rw,remount`. I keep getting `Read-only file system`.

Comment: Seems like remounting as `rw` does not work in Android 5.1.1. I ended up with booting into `TeamWin TWRP` recovery, mounting `/system` from there and doing my file operations with the integrated file manager. Of course you should have TWRP installed beforehand.

Answer (score 12):

Try

> mount -o remount,rw /system

If no error message is printed, it works.

Or, you should do the following.

First, make sure the fs type.

> mount

Issue this command to find it out.

Then

> mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system

Note that the fs(yaffs2) and device(/dev/block/mtdblock3) are depend on your system.

Comment: When done, do not forget to remount it read-only again, for safety reasons. `mount -o remount,ro /system`

Comment: This was the best solution for me. In my case, I had to expand it to specify which mount command to run. (I think there's a busybox version in xbin that is failing on my device.) `/system/bin/mount -o remount,rw /system`. I also add this line to the end my script for verification that it worked: `mount | grep yaff`.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

> mount -o rw,remount /system/

use

> mount -o rw,remount /system

mind the '/' at the end of the command.
you ask why this matters? /system/ is the directory under /system while /system is the volume name.

Answer (score 5):

You can try adb remount command also to remount /system as read write

```
adb remount
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to pass both arguments when performing a remount. You can simply pass the mount point (here /system). And /system is universal amongst Android devices.

Comment: That is dead wrong. /System is totally different on different devices

Comment: OK. I am sorry if I am wrong but you are saying that it is possible for an Android device to not have a /system directory?

Comment: No, I'm saying that on different devices, /system has different mount points. So the mount command requires both a mount point and a partition (which could be /system, /data, /ext, and a bunch of others)

Comment: What I am saying is that by issuing the mount command with the remount option there is no need to specify the partition you want to mount it to as it will use the same partition which is currently mounted to that directory (along with all of it's parameters).

Comment: That won't work all the time. The remount command works from ADB (most of the time), but it doesn't work in terminal on a lot of devices. It depends on the Android OS version and the ROM that's loaded.

Comment: How is executing the command via ADB or directly through the terminal any different? Surely it calls the same executable?! Thanks for the info though, I had no idea the functionality of the mount command differed depending on the Android version.

Comment: ADB has its own remount command. I didn't mean running it in ADB shell window, but the actual "adb remount" command. Either way, your solution isn't valid because it won't run on all ROMs & devices, and the correct solution has already been posted and accepted

Comment: @user496854 are you saying `mount -o rw,remount /system` will not work on all ROMs, but `mount -o rw,remount /path/to/partition /system` will ? Sounds like you have misunderstood @Harry

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  So here is the real answer: Mount the system under `/proc`.
Here is my command:

`mount -o rw,remount /proc /system`

It works, and in fact is the only way I can overcome the Read-only System problem.

Comment: Based on other answers, this doesn't seem to be the 'only way'. It may be convenient here, and the fact that it doesn't globally affect /system sounds good in this use case. In other situations, the whole point is to globally (though temporarily) RW for the sake of other scripts/apps.

Answer (score 2):

This is what works on my first generation Droid X with Android version 2.3.4.  I suspect that this will be universal.  Steps:

1. root system and install su.
2. Install busybox
3. Install a terminal program.
4. to mount system rw first su then

   ```
   busybox mount -o rw,remount system
   ```
5. To remount ro

   ```
   busybox mount -o ro,remount system
   ```

Note that there are no slashes on "system".

Answer (score 1):

If you have rooted your phone, but so not have busybox, only stock toybox, here a one-liner to run as root :

mount -o rw,remount $( mount | sed '/ /system /!d' | cut -d " " -f 1 ) /system

toybox do not support the "-o remount,rw" option

if you have busybox, you can use it :

busybox mount -o remount,rw /system