# installing an application programmatically in the system/app/ directory

Tags: android

I have an application that is located in the system/app directory, this application downloads and installs another app in the same path, I can download the app successfully, but when trying to install it I get the "access denied(read only file system)" error. My question is: is it even possible to do this or do I need to declare some permission for this or do I need to define my own permissions? The phone is rooted.

Comment: You need to mount /system partition as read/write which requires root

Comment: How do I go about doing that? @JohnKressel

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481395/android-how-to-mount-filesystem-in-rw-from-within-my-apk-rooted-of-course) helps

Comment: Thanks, it actually works well now without mounting the system, I had to give the app a sharedUserId of system though. I also wonder if I sign the app with the same certificate that signed the rom will I then be able to do this if the phone is not rooted?

Comment: AFAIK yes, but you'll need system sharedUserId anyway, to access that shared data. And I think you need to sign with system cert to get access to system sharedUserId, it should not be available for user apps IMO