# How to read Files from Systemfolders

Tags: android, root

I have android device with root and i try to implement some small app. This app need to read files from /proc/pid/net . I made it with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "cat /proc/"+PID+  "/net/tcp6" });` but I must  accept  su -permission for each pid. There are some other possibilities how i can to read system files in android from my app? Something with FileReader? How can I get the su-permissions without exec -commando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exec` command IS how you get `su` permissions. You might be able to `chmod 777` the files you want and then they can likely be read via java. That, or you could move the files you want to read to the sdcard, or your apps data location and read them from there. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/roottools/) is something very useful for root. You won't have to manually use the `exec` command each time, but `RootTools` does still use `exec`.

I believe if you do something like:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

you will get the root access.
And then you can do just:

```
p.getRuntime().exec("command");
```

and then you won't have to put the `su` in as long as that process is still active.

Though, I haven't done what I explained above (with the process) in quite some time, so I may be wrong. You may still have to include `su` each time. But either way, I'd recommend using `RootTools`.

Comment: great i will try RootTools. The second thing will not work, because each time you use `getRuntime().exec` it will be a new instance of terminal open and so for the second time it will have no su-permissions

Comment: Okay. I thought that might be the case, but was not sure, so thought I'd suggest anyway.

Comment: @Aprel I'd forgotten the proper way. If you go to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129144/mount-r-w-system-in-android-application-to-edit-read-only-files/8160400) you can see the proper way of using root access.