# adb remount permission denied, but able to access super user in shell -- android

Tags: android, shell, permissions, adb, root

so, i'm trying to push some files to /system on android device (zte)
I've rooted, connected with ADB,

adb remount -> I get permission denied
adb shell su -> I'm able to access shell and create folders etc and edit filesystem

(but in shell I can't copy a file from my computer to device)

Any help please

Comment: Have you tried `adb root`, then `adb remount` ?

Comment: running adb root getting -> adbd can't run as root in production builds

Comment: it's your boot.img - the default.prop or kernel must not be set up for adb remount permissions. Are you trying to push to /system somewhere? Then just run `adb shell mount -o rw,remount /system` to mount system as r/w

Comment: adb shell mount -o rw,remount /system , is giving me a 'not permitted' error, when I goto into adb shell and do SU , I can run "shell mount -o rw,remount /system" but afterwords trying to adb push to system I still get permission denied @DrakeClarris

Comment: then your boot.img or kernel needs to be changed to allow it. Are you stock and rooted? If so, try a custom rom. If you're on a custom rom, try another. Or look up how to mod a boot.img to change the ro.secure parameter - here's a guide I found on a quick google search: http://roguedroid.blogspot.com/2012/01/modding-bootimg.html (edit: don't use the dd command in the opening paragraph - you'll need to find what partition your device uses for that command)

Comment: I was on a zte u930 in china (pretty customized os) and it got stuck in boot loop and I got a replacement :-) @drakeclarris , maybe I'll just get a nexus next time

Comment: related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110927/how-to-mount-system-rewritable-or-read-only-rw-ro

Answer (score 98, accepted):

In case anyone has the same problem in the future:

```
$ adb shell
$ su
# mount -o rw,remount /system
```

Both `adb remount` and `adb root` don't work on a production build without altering ro.secure, but you can still remount /system by opening a shell, asking for root permissions and typing the mount command.

Comment: @Michael at which step are you getting the error? Is your phone rooted? What root app are you using (SuperSU, Superuser, ...)?

Comment: Step two, when I try to run "su" from the adb shell.  Phone is rooted.  I am using the Superuser app.  Is there something I need to do to tell Superuser to allow adb root access?

Comment: Not that I know of! When you run "su" you should get a Superuser popup on the phone asking if you want to authorize it. Are you sure that Superuser is working fine and that it's not configured to block adb root?

Comment: Thanks, that was it!  It *was* popping up a dialog, but I didn't see it before (screen brightness auto-dimmed so I didn't notice anything there).  Apparently after a bit it would time out and fail.

Comment: I'm not able to run `su` on my Android device, I get: `/system/bin/sh: su: not found`.  I guess it's cause my device is not rooted.

Comment: @Jayesh No, you need to be rooted to run `su`. That's pretty much the point of rooting ;)

Comment: ok, I have rooted device but I have some issue, My device is not being switched on and in offline mode id display in Eclipse device list (by connecting with usb cable in PC), but I cant push one font file(DroidSans.ttf) please read this http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53699/how-to-change-system-fonts-directory-permission-to-writable-in-switch-off-mode/53704?noredirect=1#53704

Comment: I get `mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts` on an emulator.

Comment: @BeanstheWizard they changed in API 29 I believe, it helped me to create a different emulator with older API (I used 25, android 7.0.0), that might help you.

Comment: @Kemal Tezer Dilsiz In API 28, I also got this

Comment: @tigertang I was able to do API 28 by launching emulator through cmd with --writable-system tag and then just using adb shell to go in and edit manually. I don't know if that'd work for your case. Good luck. I'm my case I only had to edit the hosts file

Comment: @Kemal Tezer Dilsiz, that only works for your emulator, rather than the real device.

Comment: @KemalTezerDilsiz When I try to start my API 28 emulator using `--writable-system`, I get `PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.` And I'm not even at the disco.

Comment: I also get `mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts` with `API 30`, but it still works somehow when I connect to my database.

Comment: Use the emulator from <path>/android-sdk/emulator/ instead of the one in <path>/android-sdk/tools/emulator

Answer (score 27):

**`emulator -writable-system`**

For people using an Emulator: Another possibility is that you need to start the emulator with -writable-system. That was the only thing that worked for me when using the standard emulator packaged with android studio with a 4.1 image. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41332316/4962858

Comment: Yes, this removes the `read-only` option from QEMU's `-drive` option: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110927/how-to-mount-system-rewritable-or-read-only-rw-ro/207200#207200 But note that it also points to a qcow2 overlay instead of the image itself, so you must then pass this option of future runs.

Answer (score 19):

Try

```
adb root
adb remount
```

to start the adb demon as root and ensure partitions are mounted in read-write mode (the essential part is `adb root`). After `push`ing, revoke root permissions again using:

```
adb unroot
```

Comment: Getting a "remount failed: no such file or directory"

Comment: `adb root`: device not found

Answer (score 15):

Some newer builds require the following additional adb commands to be run first

```
adb root
adb disable-verity
adb reboot
```

Then

```
adb root
adb remount
```

Comment: @PrzemysławSienkiewicz Same here. Nothing works with the newest emulator.

Comment: `adb disable-verity` gives me an error of `error:closed`. Any fix for this?

Comment: I doesn't work for me. After `adb remount` I get some writing data errors and finally a "remount failed".

Comment: `adb disable-verity` gives me `Device must be bootloader unlocked`

Answer (score 9):

you can use:

```
adb shell su -c "your command here"
```

only rooted devices with su works.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked on android 11, IDK why they forgot to place the remount file under bin dir. :)

Answer (score 6):

## Start /w Writable System

#### Using Emulator Images *without* Google Play

**This does ***not*** work with production Android images, i.e. ones with Google Play**

*Use non-Google Play images for root access & writeable system*

Start your emulator from a command prompt as a **writable system**, using its AVD Name (`Pixel3a` in this example, see **AVD Name** below to find or change yours. Make sure another emulator instance is *not* running when using this command):

```
emulator @Pixel3a -writable-system
```

(Keep this command handy.  You will need to use it any time you want to access your emulator as 'writable'. I use an alias in gitbash to start my emulator from a gitbash terminal, everytime.)

This launches the emulator.

When startup is complete, open another command prompt/terminal (this one is stuck running the emulator) and:

```
adb root
```

Result should be:

```
$ adb root
restarting adbd as root
```

Then:

```
adb remount
```

Result:

```
$ adb remount
remount succeeded
```

When you:

```
adb shell
```

and:

```
su
```

You should now have full root/writable access:

```
$ adb shell
generic_x86_arm:/ # su
generic_x86_arm:/ #
```

To add a domain to hosts file

```
$ cd /etc
$ cp hosts hosts.bak1
$ cat hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             ip6-localhost

$ echo '10.0.2.2 my.newdomain.com' >> hosts
$ cat hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             ip6-localhost
10.0.2.2        my.newdomain.com
```

10.0.2.2 is "localhost" for an Android emulator.  It will delegate to your Windows/Mac hosts file & DNS services.  Any domain you add to your development machine's `hosts` file, will work as `10.0.2.2` on your Android Emulator hosts file.

#### AVD Name

In Android Studio AVD Manager can be launched from menu:

Tools > AVD Manager

[image: AVD List]

If your emulator name has spaces, you can change that by clicking the pencil icon on right hand side.

I named my emulator 'Pixel3a' without spaces for ease of typing.
[image: AVD Details]

Comment: These are the only instructions I've found that work. Set up a new emulated Pixel 4a device w/ Android 12.0, and I was able to update the hosts to access a local development server running on Vagrant. Thank you!

(If anyone's curious, because of how Vagrant works I used the *same* IP I have in my host machine's `/etc/hosts` file: 192.168.56.5.

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted to recovery
then

```
adb root; adb adb remount system;
```

worked for me
my recovery is twrp v3.5

Answer (score -1):

Try with an API lvl 28 emulator (Android 9).
I was trying with api lvl 29 and kept getting errors.

Answer (score -5):

```
@echo off
color 0B
echo =============================================================================
echo.
echo              ClockworkMod Recovery for SAMSUNG GALAXY SIII E210L
echo.
echo                  ClockworkMod Recovery (v6.0.1.2 Touch)
echo.
echo     ¡ô¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¡ô
echo     ¨U                                                                  ¨U
echo     ¨U SAMSUNG GALAXY SIII E210L                                        ¨U
echo     ¡ô¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¨T¡ô
echo.
echo  1) (Settings\Developer options©¥ USB debugging)
echo.
echo  2) CWM SAMSUNG GALAXY SIII E210L 
echo.
echo  3) THANK!!!!!!
echo.
echo =============================================================================
echo                           ARE YOU READY? GO! ¡·¡·¡·
@pause
echo.
echo adb...
adb.exe kill-server
adb.exe wait-for-device
echo wiat¸!
echo.
echo conect...
adb.exe push IMG /data/local/tmp/
adb.exe shell su -c "dd if=/data/local/tmp/GANGSTAR-VEGAS-1.3.0-APK-Andropalace.net.apk of=/mnt/sdcard/Android/GANGSTAR-VEGAS-1.3.0-APK-Andropalace.net.apk
adb.exe shell su -c "rm /data/local/tmp/bootloader.img"
adb.exe shell su -c "rm /data/local/tmp/recovery.img"


echo ===============================================================
echo     ClockworkMod Recovery!
echo.
@pause
```

Comment: a little bit of explanation along with your code might go a long way

Comment: You can delete the answer if you don't want to carry with so many downvotes