# How can I remount my Android/system as read-write in a bash script using adb?

Tags: android, bash, adb, mount

For info

```
adb remount
```

returns `"remount failed: Operation not permitted"`

```
adb shell 'su -c  mount -o rw,remount /system'
```

returns `unknown option -- o`

My device is rooted.

Comment: This is not answerable in the general case.  Android's mount command is atypical and the exact details of what invocation it needs (often a specific device file as well as mount point) are device/version specific.  Further, it's quite likely that the -o is not being passed through to the mount command, but processed as an argument to su.

Comment: From reading other posts, it seem that it cannot necessarilty be done. "your boot.img or kernel needs to be changed to allow it. Are you stock and rooted? If so, try a custom rom". I will let you know if I find a workaround.

Comment: That's a distinct issue, that the hardware might be enforcing write protection below filesystem level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adb remount permission denied, but able to access super user in shell -- android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089694/adb-remount-permission-denied-but-able-to-access-super-user-in-shell-android)

Comment: since android 10/11 it's not possible, you have to create a tmpfs: https://medium.com/@anthony.f.tannous/android-10-emulation-of-magisk-supersu-on-an-aosp-avd-de93ed080fad

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Probable cause that `remount` fails is you are not running `adb` as `root`.

Shell Script should be as follow.

```
# Script to mount Android Device as read/write.
# List the Devices.
adb devices;

# Run adb as root (Needs root access).
adb root;

# Since you're running as root su is not required
adb shell mount -o rw,remount /;
```

If this fails, you could try the below:

```
# List the Devices.
adb devices;

# Run adb as root
adb root;

adb remount;
adb shell su -c "mount -o rw,remount /";
```

To find which `user` you are:

```
$ adb shell whoami
```

Comment: These may or may not work - Android mount command is a bit atypical and in many cases has wanted the exact device specified.

Comment: I have tried the above on Android 4.4.4 (Google Nexus), Adb v 1.0.31

Comment: adb shell su -c "mount -o rw,remount /system";
Seems to work - thanks a lot

Comment: "adb root" didn't work on my HTC Desire 510.  "adbd cannot run as root in production builds"

Comment: Using an Emulator, none of the above worked unless I launched the AVD with the `-writeable-system` flag

Comment: since android 10/11 it's not possible, you have to create a tmpfs: https://medium.com/@anthony.f.tannous/android-10-emulation-of-magisk-supersu-on-an-aosp-avd-de93ed080fad

Comment: After I run `adb shell whoami` it shows `shell`. What should I do next?

Answer (score 15):

I could not get the mount command to work without specifying the dev block to mount as /system

`#cat /proc/mounts` returns ( only the system line here )
`/dev/stl12 /system rfs ro,relatime,vfat,log_off,check=no,gid/uid/rwx,iocharset=utf8 0 0`

so my working command is
`mount -o rw,remount -t rfs /dev/stl12 /system`

Comment: Thanks, that format did it for me on Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1. Command ended up being: mount -o rw,remount -t ext4 /dev/block/platform/soc.0/f9824900.sdhci/by-name/system /system

Comment: The only answer that actually works on Android 6.0.1. Good job sir.

Answer (score 15):

Otherwise...  if

```
getenforce
```

returns

```
Enforcing
```

Then maybe you should call

```
setenforce 0 
mount -o rw,remount /system 
setenforce 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't allowed.  `type=1400 audit(1678982139.040:13): avc: denied { setenforce } for pid=1195 comm="setenforce" scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:kernel:s0 tclass=security permissive=0` then `setenforce: Couldn't set enforcing status to '0': Permission denied`

Answer (score 6):

The following may help (study the impacts of `disable-verity` first):

```
adb root
adb disable-verity
adb reboot
```

Comment: Thanks this was help full in Oreo devices

Comment: `adb disable-verity` gives me an error of `error:closed`. Any reason/fix for this?

Comment: `disable-verity only works for userdebug builds`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and could not mount system as read/write. It would return

> Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type]
>   device directory

Or

> operation not permitted. Access denied

Now this works on all rooted devices.

**DO THE FOLLOWING IN `TERMINAL EMULATOR` OR  IN `ADB SHELL`**

```
$ su
#mount - o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /system
```

`Yaffs2` is the type of system partition. Replace it by the type of your system partition as obtained from executing the following

```
#cat /proc/mounts
```

Then check where `/system` is appearing from the lengthy result

Extract of mine was like

```
mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.3/by-num/p10 /system ext4 ro,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.3/by-num/p11 /cache ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

So my system is `ext4`. And my command was

```
$ su
#mount  -o  rw,remount  -t  ext4  /system
```

Done.

Comment: I got "mount: Permission denied" : \

Answer (score 1):

Get "adbd insecure" from google play store, it helps give write access to custom roms that have it secured my the manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the other answers you received, I want to explain the `unknown option -- o` error: Your command was

```
$ adb shell 'su -c  mount -o rw,remount /system'
```

which calls su through adb.  You properly quoted the whole su command in order to pass it as *one* argument to `adb shell`.  However, `su -c <cmd>` also needs you to quote the command with arguments it shall pass to the shell's `-c` option.  (YMMV depending on `su` variants.)  Therefore, you might want to try

```
$ adb shell 'su -c "mount -o rw,remount /system"'
```

(and potentially add the actual device listed in the output of `mount | grep system` before the `/system` arg – see the other answers.)

Answer (score 0):

```
mount -o rw,remount $(mount | grep /dev/root | awk '{print $3}')
```

this does the job for me, and should work for any android version.