# adb remount fails - mount: 'system' not in /proc/mounts

Tags: android, adb, mount

I tried all the commands and suggestions available in stackoverflow and online but none worked

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13366444/1441666
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28018008

and many more but nothing works for me

I am getting below error - None of below commands are working.

```
$adb root
$adb disable-verity
```

For

```
$adb remount
remount of / failed: Permission denied
remount failed
```

So then I tried with different commands like

```
$ adb shell mount -o rw,remount /system
mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts

$ adb shell mount -o rw,remount /
'/dev/root' is read-only


$ adb shell  mount -o rw,remount -t /dev/block/stl12 system
mount: 'system' not in /proc/mounts

$ adb shell "su 0 mount -o rw,remount /system"
mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts

$ adb shell
$ su
# mount -o rw,remount /system

 mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts
```

Comment: this might help you, as working for me with the same issue `https://github.com/d4rken/sdmaid-public/issues/2110#issuecomment-440325101`

Answer (score 48):

I had the same issue.The solution is to mount the root (/). After this you can write to /system.

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Don't forget to reset the state to 'ro'.

```
mount -o ro,remount /
```

Comment: Sadly I'm getting `'/dev/block/dm-4' is read-only` when I run this command

Comment: It does not work for new Samsung T870 models mounting `/system` as read-only.

Comment: Tears. ```mount: '/dev/block/dm-0' not user mountable in fstab```

Comment: No result achieved with this

Comment: worked for me :)

Comment: Warning! Take a system backup before executing `ro`, on a real device. I had my device stuck at boot logo, glad restored it from recovery.

Comment: on Google android emulator getting error: `'/dev/root' is read-only`
Tried on Android 9.0 arm64

Comment: this worked for Xiaomi redmi device

Comment: **Warning** when modifying the system partition! If your ROM checks agains integrity or similar, you'll softbrick your device.

Answer (score 26):

```
> adb root
> adb shell avbctl disable-verification
Successfully disabled verification. Reboot the device for changes to take effect.
> adb disable-verity
using overlayfs
Successfully disabled verity
Now reboot your device for settings to take effect
> adb reboot
> adb root && adb remount
remount succeeded
> adb push ScreenCap.apk /system/app/
ScreenCap.apk: 1 file pushed. 33.1 MB/s (1640812 bytes in 0.047s)
> adb reboot
```

Comment: On the second command, I get "/system/bin/sh: avbctl: not found"

Comment: `/system/bin/sh: avbctl: inaccessible or not found`

Comment: The command `adb shell avbctl disable-verification` working for me during 2020, but now I get the same error of here above: "/system/bin/sh: avbctl: inaccessible or not found". I don't know why.

Comment: Probably the solution is pick up an emulator image that don't belong to Play Store (without that icon on AVD Manager into Android Studio). And with a "Q" Android version. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45668555/7191548

Comment: Finally I found this worked answer. thank you a lot!

Comment: Getting
"avb_ops_user.cpp:217: ERROR: Error writing data" for the 2nd command

Answer (score 21):

(Android Q Emulator `solution`)

```
> emulator -avd Pixel_3a_XL_API_30 -writable-system
> adb shell avbctl disable-verification
> adb disable-verity
> adb root
> adb remount
> adb shell "su 0 mount -o rw,remount /system"
```

Comment: this works, thanks! tested with android 10 emulator

Comment: `verity cannot be disabled/enabled - USER build`. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: @Egret, on what type of device you are trying it? 
(`adb disable-verity` is the issue right? try to skip it may work)

Answer (score 9):

If you are getting /system not in /proc/mounts error, your device system partition is not mounted with any directory. Writing to the system partition is restricted.

If you are using emulator please download previous version system image.

As of now, Android Q is not supported for writing the system partition so use android pie instead.

Comment: This answer basically repeats the first one. The main problem with both is that lowering the API level is not a future-proof solution. Also, please include some source stating doing this is "not supported" on Android Q.

Comment: @Magudesh, where has it been stated that Android Q does not support writing to the system partition on a rooted device?

Comment: @avelyne  Rooting the android Q was supported in devices but not in emulator. If Android R released, rooting for android Q will be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the first answer of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923996/adb-root-is-not-working-on-emulator-cannot-run-as-root-in-production-builds?noredirect=1&lq=1).
To make it so that the error `adbd cannot run as root in production builds` does not pop up you have to choose an emulator system image that is not labelled "Google Play".
After that you have to run:

```
./adb root
```

Cold Boot your device once, then run:

```
% ./adb shell
$ su
# mount -o rw,remount /system
```

and you should be good to run any of the commands you had on your question.
For me I had to choose a Hardware without the "Play Store" logo under the Play Store column like in this photo:
(keep in mind that the UI of Android Studio might change)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently running Android 13 on Samsung s20 Ultra (SM-G988B) and what worked for me was the following via terminal in TWRP recovery.

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Then, to de-bloat /product/app/Chrome for example:

```
chmod 777 /product
```

deleted what i needed then returned the permissions to

```
chmod 644 /product
```

Comment: The other thing that is worth mentioning is when you are in custom recovery and you would like to debloat either /system/app or priv-app, you most likely will need to mount -o rw,remount in / again, as the normal system dir is located inside the system_root dir via custom recovery.

Answer (score -1):

I met this issue when working on rockchip tablet device running on Android OS 8.1. And I found a way to remount the /system to rw as the steps below:

1. adb shell
2. su
3. mount | grep system
4. After step 3 you will see the cmd print out this :

   > **/dev/block/mmcblk1p11** on /system type **ext4** (ro,dirsync,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered,inod
   >   e_readahead_blks=8)

   (the type and path maybe different depend on your device)
5. Now use the command:

   > busybox mount -o remount,rw –t **<-type>** **<-path>** /system

In my case, **<-type>** is **ext4** and **<-path>** is **/dev/block/mmcblk1p11**

Hope this can help someone!

Answer (score -3):

I encountered this issue with Android API `28`.

The walk-around was to use a lower version Android API level `24`. After that everything works.

[image: ADV]

```
$ adb shell
generic_x86:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system
generic_x86:/ # exit
[~]
$ adb push /etc/hosts /system/etc/hosts
/etc/hosts: 1 file pushed. 2.2 MB/s (7458 bytes in 0.003s)
```