# Android 11 - ROOT : mount /system fails with not found in /proc/system

Tags: android, root, android-11

My OS is PixysOS - Android 11
When I do

```
mount -o rw,remount /system
```

It fails saying -

```
mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts
```

But usually it worked. I've also tested in android 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62653020/14797617

Looks like I've to mount the root (/) directory.

mount -o rw,remount /

Comment: For those like me who haven't done in-depth android stuff like this in a while, It should be noted that you still won't be able to mount /system as re-writable after this, but the /system location will now be writable. The system partition *is* the root now, for newer devices that are "system as root" style partition layout:
[system as root explaination](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/partitions/system-as-root)

[relevant answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213167/how-does-magisk-work/213344#213344)

[another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62653020/3128017)

Answer (score 3):

Exit adb shell, then:

```sh
$ adb root
$ adb disable-verity
$ adb remount
$ adb shell
$ mount -o rw,remount /
```

Comment: Doesn't work on physical smartphone.