# Android 11, rooted (Magisk): mount system_ext in read/write to remove Google Apps

Tags: android, adb

I want to remove Google apps and services on a new Fairphone 4 (Android 11, now rooted using Magisk. No TWRP build available yet.).

To this end, I am trying to use [microG](https://github.com/microg). In the [Prerequisites](https://github.com/microg/GmsCore/wiki/Prerequisites) for its usage, signature spoofing and deleting files in `system/priv-app` are listed. For signature spoofing, I followed the *XPosed solution for Android 11 and 12* listed [here](https://github.com/microg/GmsCore/wiki/Signature-Spoofing), i.e. using Magisk + riru + LSPosed + a FakeGApps fork. Not sure, whether or not this worked. All individual steps reported success, but the [Signature Spoofing Checker](https://github.com/Lanchon/sigspoof-checker) says it didn't work.

Anyway, I'm definitely stuck at the second step, because I don't seem to be able to delete any files in `system_ext/priv-app`. I tried the solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65463354/android-11-root-mount-system-fails-with-not-found-in-proc-system) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55030788/adb-remount-fails-mount-system-not-in-proc-mounts/62653020#62653020).
If I try

```
adb shell
su
# then confirm on the phone, then
mount -o rw,remount /
```

I get `'/dev/block/dm-0' is read-only`. Similar error (with `dm-1`) if I try mounting `/system_ext`.

`adb root` or `adb disable-verity` don't work, because it's a user build: `adbd cannot run as root in production builds`, `verity cannot be disabled/enabled - USER build`.

I even tried to write a Magisk module to replace the directories in question with empty ones, by putting the following in the `customize.sh`:

```
REPLACE="
/system_ext/priv-app/GoogleFeedback
/system_ext/priv-app/GoogleOneTimeInitializer
/system_ext/priv-app/GoogleServicesFramework
/system_ext/priv-app/SetupWizard
/system/system_ext/priv-app/GoogleFeedback
/system/system_ext/priv-app/GoogleOneTimeInitializer
/system/system_ext/priv-app/GoogleServicesFramework
/system/system_ext/priv-app/SetupWizard
"
```

I think `/system/system_ext` and `/system_ext` are hard linked, but not sure whether that matters. After loading that module and rebooting, the contents of those folders are still the same when checking with `adb shell`.

Any ideas?

For `adb` I'm using my desktop with Ubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the question simultaneously on the XDA Forums, and [got a reply there](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/fairphone-4-remove-google-apps-microg.4379791/).

At the stage described above (unlocked bootloader, Magisk, signature spoofing with riru + LSPosed), all that's needed is to install NanoDroid with microG as a Magisk module. Download the current NanoDroid-microG zip from here:

https://downloads.nanolx.org/NanoDroid/Stable/

either on your phone directly or transfer it to your phone, then install it as a Magisk module from storage. Voilà, GApps are removed (or at least inaccessible) and microG works. Best to then update microG, e.g. via its F-Droid repo: https://microg.org/download.html.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this using a raspberry pi-based system without the need to mess with priv-app.

Putting aside all of the modules and different software programs that can be used, the signature management/spoofing information is located in /system/framework/services.jar. This is the file that must be modified to enable signature spoofing.

https://whiteboxcellphone.com/psd/microg-rpi.html has links to java classes that implement signature spoofing and explains how to insert them into services.jar using DexPatcher.

Once you have a patched services.jar, you only need to put it back on the system without disturbing the file permissions and then use f-droid to install microG, Fakestore and FakeGapps.

You'll also need a signature spoofing permission manager (see link above) because you don't want every app in town to pretend to be play services.

Anyway, those are the fundamentals. Magisk, Xposed, etc are just ways of getting there.

Edit: I see that you need to mess with priv-app if Google's services were previously installed. Leaving this response up because it is important to have a fundamental understanding of what is going on instead of a series of apps and modules that must be used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).