# Android 12: adb root. adbd cannot run as root in production builds

Tags: android, adb, root

There is a need to install your application as a system one. To do this, I rooted the Samsung A04 (Android 12) using Magisk.
Next, to install my app, I wanted to copy it to /system/priv-app using

```
adb push /system/priv-app
```

To do this, it was necessary to activate root via

```
adb root
```

but this command gave an error

> adbd cannot run as root in production builds

I started looking on the Internet for ways to solve this problem, I tried to install

1. adbd Insecure - the program closes with an error when activated in
   the settings of the desired item
2. adb_root (plugin in Magisk) - adb root still gave

   > adbd cannot run as root in production builds error
3. MagiskHide Props Config - changing the **ro.debuggable** and **ro.secure**
   values blocked the connection of the phone to the PC (the phone was
   no longer recognized as an external device and when entering the
   "Developer options" section, the section was closed with an error)

Perhaps someone faced this problem on Android 12 and was able to solve it?

I read that many people have had this problem since Android 11.

Perhaps there is another solution to make the application system?

Thanks in advance

Comment: adb root has never and will never work unless you use a specially modified custom ROM (which 99% of all custom ROMs and 100% stock ROMs are not). Better try to remount the partition the file you want to modify is saved on as rw using `su` and `mount` command.

Comment: If you mean remount the partition where I need to copy my application file, then I have already tried to do this and I get an error similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55030788/adb-remount-fails-mount-system-not-in-proc-mounts), including the error from the comments on the first answer

Comment: @CamilleLouédoc Didn't find a solution. While refused rooting. I managed to solve my problem for which I rooted the device, differently

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded with this module for Magisk, try it maybe it will work
https://github.com/anasfanani/Adb-Root-Enabler/releases/tag/v1.2