# Problem with adb root on Samsung Galaxy A04e on Android 12

Tags: android, adb, root, adbd

I rooted a new Samsung Galaxy A04e on Android 12 using Magisk.
I can "adb shell" and su to root no problem.
But when I try to do an "adb root" then I get the "production device" issue that others have reported.

The problem is that adbd cannot run as root on a rooted Galaxy A04e running Android 12 (at least how I rooted it!)

From what I understand it is to the adbd service on the phone that needs to be "patched". So I tried the "adbd insecure" apk, and granted that app root access through Magisk, but the app fails the patching.
It seems the adbd insecure apk does not work on Android 12.

Does anyone know what I could do, so adb root works?

Is there any image for A40e running either Android 12 or 13 that I could use and would have adbd rootable? I need the image to be as close as a standard Android 12/13 version (but fully rooted :).

On that link, it seems that Ilya Filimonov managed to find a solution, but there is no detail and I was unable to contact that person.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75212388/android-12-adb-root-adbd-cannot-run-as-root-in-production-builds/76463747#76463747](https://stackoverflow.com)

Any help would be Welcome!
Thanks.
G.

Comment: Rooting does never automatically enable `adb root`. For `adb root` you usually have to set adb.insecure=1 or even replace the adbd on Android side because the default versions drops root permission in the start process thus `adb root` can not work afterwards.