# Why am I getting Permission Denied when trying to push a Sqlite file to my rooted Android device?

Tags: android, shell, permissions, adb, root

So I have a local `Sqlite` file I am trying to push to my ***Rooted*** Android (Nexus 7 2013) device. Which I have confirmed is ***Rooted*** by tying `adb shell`, `su` and seeing the **#** displayed instead of **$**

I am trying to run the following command:

```
adb push D:\tfs\MyApp\MyDatabase.db3 /data/data/MyApp/files/MyDatabase.db3
```

But I keep getting

> Failed to copy ...MyApp.. to ...MyApp...: Permission denied

I have searched the internet and found answers [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1633788) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089694/adb-remount-permission-denied-but-able-to-access-super-user-in-shell-android) and have come up with the following:

```
adb shell su -c "mount -o rw,remount /data"
adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data"
```

But even after running these two above commands and running my `Push` Command I am still getting **Permission Denied**.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so heres my solution.

My phone was already ***Rooted*** but for some reason this isnt enough to do anything you want.

I had to go and download the apk onto my device named **adbd insecure** mentioned [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1687590)  which you can download on that thread or from the [google play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.adbd). I then had to open the App on my device and click **"Enable Insecure adbd"** and I also clicked **"Enable at boot"**

After this running my normal command:

```
adb push D:\tfs\MyApp\MyDatabase.db3 /data/data/MyApp/files/MyDatabase.db3
```

worked

Answer (score 21):

'adb push' cannot push to data/data/ directory.
However, you can do it by using a transfer station like this:

```
adb push D:\tfs\MyApp\MyDatabase.db3 ~/sdcard/MyDatabase.db3
```

`adb shell`

```
su

mv /sdcard/MyDatabase.db3 /data/data/MyApp/files/MyDatabase.db3
```

It works for me,good luck to you.

Comment: You just save me another 30 minutes trying to push a custom APK file to /data/temp folder.

Comment: In Linux the command to copy sdcard is `./adb push ~/fastdroid-vnc /sdcard/fastdroid-vnc`

Answer (score 3):

To push an APK file Eg:"MyApp" to `/data/local/tmp/` from my local `C:/Apps`

`adb push C:/Apps/MyApp /data/local/tmp/` is giving Permission Denied error

Steps to make this work (issue these commands in an order)

1. `adb shell`
2. `su`
3. `chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/`
4. `exit`
5. `chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/`
6. `exit`

Now if i give adb push, it worked

```
adb push C:/Apps/MyApp /data/local/tmp/
```

Comment: Why are steps 3 and 4 repeated?

Comment: One step is for root user and after exiting from it, then the other one is for current user

Answer (score 3):

## Simple solution:

- Instead of:
  `.\adb.exe push c:/files-to-push.zip /mnt/sdcard/Download`
- I used:
  `.\adb.exe push c:/files-to-push.zip /sdcard/Download`

## The problem I had

After going to adb folder(in my case `c:/adb`)

I connected with:
`.\adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:58526`

And then I tried to push this zip file `c:/Games/pokemon.zip` by running:

`.\adb.exe push c:/Games/pokemon.zip /mnt/sdcard/Download`

I got this error:

`adb: error: stat failed when trying to push to /mnt/sdcard/Download: Permission denied`

## Explaining my solution:

I was trying to push files to a path that does not exist...

In my case I tried to push to `/mnt/sdcard/Download`

Then after running `adb shell` I got access to console

Finally just typed `ls` to check which folder I had there

In my case I saw there was no `/mnt`

So after that I tried to `ls /sdcard` and saw `Download` folder there...

Answer (score 0):

Run the commands below:

```
adb root
```

or

```
adb wait-for-device root && adb remount
```