# Error during Flutter connection to localhost DB

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

Am trying  to connect to connect flutter to local xampp, it executes with the above error, any help is appreciated

SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = [192.168.1.254](https://192.168.1.254), port = 38614

Answer (score 0):

1- if you are using emulator use  `10.0.2.2` instead of  `192.168.1.254`

2- if you are using physical device make sure the device is connected to server first without the flutter app by accessing the ip of the server from your device or 10.0.2.2 if emulator

3- try disabling your firewall and antivirus

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your emulator doesn't have access to IP 192.168.1.254 on your host machine.

You can test this by opening up Chrome in your emulator and trying to visit: http://192.168.1.254

The Android emulator provides access to your host machine through IP 10.0.2.2.  So if you have a website running at localhost (127.0.0.1) on your host machine, you should be able to access that from Android emulator Chrome browser using http://10.0.2.2

Android emulator also delegates DNS queries via 10.0.2.2.  So if your host machine hosts file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` or `/etc/hosts` on Mac) has domains specified (such as `192.168.1.254  myxampp`) then you can edit your emulator's hosts file to delegate the domain lookup to your host machine hosts file using:

```
10.0.2.2 myxampp
```

Here are some [instructions on how to edit your emulator's hosts file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66557437/2301224) if you decide to go that route.